# Find a period if $f(x+k)=1+(2-5f(x)+10f(x)^2-10f(x)^3+5f(x)^4-f(x)^5)^{\frac{1}{5}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations, periodic-functions

> Let $f$ be a real valued function with domain $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying,
>   $$f(x+k)=1+(2-5f(x)+10f(x)^2-10f(x)^3+5f(x)^4-f(x)^5)^{\frac{1}{5}}$$
>   for all real $x$ and some positive constant $k$, then find the period
>   of $f(x)$ if it is periodic.

**My Attempt:**

$$f(x+k)=1+(1+(C_0^5(1)^5(-f(x))^0+C_1^5(1)^4(-f(x))+C_2^5(1)^3(-f(x))^2+C_3^5(1)^2(-f(x))^3+C_4^5(1)^1(-f(x))^4+C_5^5(1)^0(-f(x))^5))^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

$$f(x+k)=1+(1+(1-f(x)^5)^{\frac{1}{5}}$$

The problem is that I am not able to establish $f(x)$ is periodic. How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $g(x) = (1-f(x))^5+1/2$ and you have $$g(x+k)=-g(x)$$

so $$g(x+2k) =-g(x+k)=g(x)$$

so $g$ has period $2k$.

So $$(1-f(x+2k))^5 = (1-f(x))^5\implies 1-f(x+2k) = 1-f(x)$$ and so $f$ has also period $2k$.

Comment: A great answer but how was $g(x)=(1-f(x))^5+\frac{1}{2}$ intuitive?

Comment: It is not intiutive, you just go step by step with substitution. Look at your first comment. At that time we have $g(x)+g(x+2k)=-1$, so why not add to each part on left 1/2 and let that be new function say $h(x)$ or as I did.

Comment: So I should substitute to make the functions neat and easier to solve as to these hefty expressions right?

Comment: Yes, substitution is a magic word, at least for me.